# How to run a .war without a main class from command and heroku?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, heroku, war, program-entry-point

I have a spring mvc, maven CRUD webapp without a main class, and no executable classes.
It has a couple of .jsp pages that run when called from Controller class.

It has Appinitializer which i guess uses Spring MVC to start the app. It also has a class with Viewresolver which i guess configures the controller. I package it to .war .

It runs on tomcat localhost fine, but when I try to run it on commandline or heroku local web it keeps asking for main file (no main manifest attribute). any clues how to find the file to execute? I dont have any executable classes or main class.

Heres what appinitializer looks like:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a Tomcat on Heroku just as you do on your local machine. Heroku offers a solution for your use-case which is described here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner